# Is the Secure Canvas URL required for Localhost apps in development

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate

I am developing an application in my local machine.

I let users invite their Facebook friends with a Facebook request Dialogue.

The friends then click the link in their Facebook and are directed to the canvas page and then redirected out of Facebook to my local site.

Do I need to have an SSL certificate and if so how can I have one when I am developing locally so I can test my site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Facebook Oct.1 deadline blog post, SSL is not required for sandbox apps. So you can continue to develop apps without SSL certificate as long as you enable sandbox in your app.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, temporary *DISABLE* secure browsing setting in 'Account Setting'.

http://gyazo.com/39e4dd5087636ebc3024d2285ab3e33a.png

Comment: facebook does not have this option anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Forward works great for developing facebook apps locally, supports SSL too.

https://forwardhq.com/in-use/facebook

Answer (score 0):

You need a certificate before October 1st, otherwise your canvas landing page will be blocked by Facebook. If you develop locally and need a SSL cert just for test, see the following trick for IIS:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx